# Simple AJAX Submit and update mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am stumped, I am tossing out my code and I need help with a cross browser ajax submit.
Can anyone PLEASE give me a simple working ajax submit script for updating mysql? The one I have is all bad.

Works in FF and Safarai (iphone), but in IE7, it has caching problem and in IE8 it doesn't even submit.

Comment: Sometimes it's far quicker and easier for everyone to simply write a new script. And most of the time, if they have taken the time to explain why they aren't using their script, chances are it's beyond repair (within a reasonable amount of time)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best/safest bet is to use a library which provides AJAX functionality. You can roll your own, but odds are it will not be as stable or full-featured as library code.

jQuery, for example, supports AJAX:
http://jquery.com/

If you decide you're determined to roll your own, or want to learn more about the innards of AJAX, check out the w3schools tutorial (which includes sample AJAX code):

http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

ok since you want to use any script I will use my favorite one ExtJS

```
<?php

// Submit.php

mysql_connect();
$_POST['text'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comment(text) VALUES('{$_POST['text']}')");

die('{sucess: true}');

========== form.html

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/ext-core/3/ext-core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Ext.onReady(function(){
                Ext.fly('form').on('submit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var t = Ext.fly('text').dom.value;
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                       url: 'submit.php',
                       success: function(){ alert('ok!'); },
                       failure: function() { alert('nok!') ; }, 
                       params: { text: t }
                    });
                    return false;               
                });         
            });     
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form">
            <input id="text" type="text" name="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to add something like this to ur request url like: ?rand=someRandomTimeGeneratedWithJavasciptGreatJob

make sure.. on your button it's like this...

<input type="button" onclick="ajax('url'); return false;"> don't ask me why this works, it just does.

also, screw jqweery USE prototype -> prototypejs.org